# capture string between characters with jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable which contains "j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input" (without the quotes).

Now I would like to capture "MyFieldName".

I had this:

```
var test = "j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input";
var testRE = test.match(":(.*).input");
console.log("old text: " + test);
console.log("new text: " + testRE[1]);
```

which outputs this:

```
old text: j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input
new text: j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName
```

So what I need is telling him that I want everything between the **last occurence** ":" and ".input", because now he finds the first ':' and stops there.

Any ideas how I can realise this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option that remains (among, presumably, many others) is:

```
var str = "j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input",
    fieldName = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WSbwh/1/).

References:

- [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
- [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this without regular expressions:

```
var test = "j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input";
var fieldName = test.split(':').pop().split('.')[0];
```

Comment: This isn't a criticism of your approach, but is there a reason to *not* use `testParts.pop().split('.')[0]`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Very nice... I always forget about the pop method!

Comment: I'm not sure. I find regexes difficult to read and debug, so I stay away from them when I can

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work:

```
.*:(.*)\.input
```

Comment: @dystroy no. By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match as many times as possible and therefore match the last occurence of ":". Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/m4e6d/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that it matches the first `:`, and then captures everything `(.*)` up until `.input`. To avoid this, you can make sure that your capture between `:` and `.input` cannot include more `:`.

This regex should work for you:

```
/:(\w+)\.input/
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4e6d/)

```
var test = "j_id0:j_id11:i:f:pb:d:MyFieldName.input";
var testRE = test.match(/:(\w+)\.input/)
console.log("old text: " + test);
console.log("new text: " + testRE[1]); //MyFieldName
```

Group 1 will contain your field name.

I think the above should work for you, but if you need more than `\w` characters, you could use this instead to allow for things like "...:My.Field.Name.input" and capture "My.Field.Name":

```
/:([^:]+)\.input/
```